# Tracking extra information for Celery results

Tags: python, celery

I'm looking at tracking extra data around my celery tasks. By default it has a task_id, status, results, date completed. I was hoping to track which exact task type and variables used (i.e. image_rendering img_id:2, image_resizing img_id:5).

Is there a way to add to the existing table or am I better off creating a second table that references the task_id and create that entry when the task is created?

FYI using postgresql as a backend.